# Can't connect to AWS RDS after setting up Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I am pretty confused, this is a procedure I've done a lots of times in the past, without any issue.

My objective, after setting up a RDS I create and make sure is active a Security Group allowing all incomming traffic from any IP, 0.0.0.0/0.

I am trying to connect from an external source to the server, yet I fail to, and having problems on how further investgating what is the issue.

The access to 1433 ports is open by the firewall I'm using.

I don't know how to proceed.

Kind regards,
Alejandro.

Comment: Have you set your RDS to be publicly accessible when you set it up? If you are deployed into a VPC, do you have a NACL on the VPC which locks it down?

Comment: @Henry, yes. Publicly Accessible: Yes and for the VPC yes I have it deployed into a VPC, yet I never had an issue with this, I will further investigate this topic, if you can provide any info It'd be more than welcome.

Comment: The only obvious points would be whether you have a security group or NACL compatible, and whether you set it publicly accessible or not. Spin up an EC2 instance in your VPC and see if you can ping it? Maybe the route tables of the VPC? Can you RDP/SSH into an EC2 instance in your VPC?

Comment: Hey @Henry, thanks for the support so far. I tried launching an EC2 and ping its public DNS. No luck either and in my security group I had my IP to be allowed to send any traffic. Also I checked ACL and made the same settigns, all incmoing and outgoing traffic by my IP should be allowed.

Comment: Sorry, no obvious issues left for me without being able to access the account. It's worth sending in a ticket to support, and updating this when you resolve it

Comment: Damn it.. I don't have access to support sadly as I'm using free tier account. I will have to do it by myself then I guess!

Comment: Try the aws subreddit - there are some tech support guys there who can help too